# convert date August 22, 2016 to 08/22/2016?

Tags: php

I have this date format: `August 22, 2016`

I want to convert to `08/22/2016`

str_replace is the solution?
eg: `str_replace("August","08/",$var);`
but it should have at least 12 str_replaces...

any ideas for a simple way?

Comment: Start reading manuals. `php date convert` will show you a lot of ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Refer to [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)
>
> Specify your desired date format **'m/d/Y'** after creating the DateTime object.

Try this:

```
$date = new DateTime('August 22, 2016');
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');  // 08/22/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$originalDate = "August 22, 2016";
$newDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
08/22/2016
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/1mnAA)**

Answer (score 0):

just like php date function convert to in strtotime,

**Example**:

```
$date = "August 22, 2016";
$date2 = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($date));
echo $date2;
```

**ANS** : `08/22/2016`

Note: if you change date format so change in date function so u like